# this._delegate.setNgStyle is not a function after Angular 8 update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

after updating my project from angular 7 to angular 8 and fixing all errors caused by breaking changes im facing the following problem:

```
<div fxFill ngStyle.xs="overflow:auto">
```

The line above is giving me the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: this._delegate.setNgStyle is not a function

any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your code should be

```
[ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}"
```

or

```
[style.xs]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly both ways are not working. If im using this, my application is crashing way before my initial error is coming up.

Comment: @FelixGerber check my answer again

Comment: We'll that dies trick! Thanks. But I dosen't exactly get why... do you have any sources for me or some extra informations?

Comment: Go to angular.io abd search for ngStyle you will see some code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Updating FlexLayout to latest version, fixed the issue for me. 
From "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.19"
To "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.26"